# Как в web-приложении java(tomcat) сохранять сессию при закрытии браузера

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, tomcat, spring-security

Использую spring-security для реализации аутентификации в web-приложении.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/views/*" access="permitAll()" requires-channel="http"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/views/inf/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="http"/>
    <form-login login-page="/views/login.xhtml" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"/>

    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
        <password-encoder ref="encoder"></password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl"
            class="com.special.news.monitor.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl"/>

<beans:bean id="encoder"
            class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
</beans:bean>
```

В свой web.xml добавил

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Я заметил, что, когда браузер открыт, я захожу на страницу, ввожу логин и пароль, закрываю страницу(сам браузер остаётся открытым) и сессия сохраняется на протяжении 60 минут(как и должно быть), а если закрыть браузер и открыть снова, то сессия тут же закрывается, и приходится заново вводить логин и пароль. Как сделать так, чтобы даже после зыкрытия браузера сессия продолжала быть открытой на протяжении заданного времени и не пришлось заново логиниться.

P.s. провел эксперимент, если у firefox нажать на restore previous session, то тогда заново логиниться не нужно. Моя сессия как бы восстанавливается, но в chrome такого инструмента нет, да и у сторонних web-приложений это реализовано так, что и в firefox'e не нужно ни на что нажимать , а просто ввести ссылку на сайт и сессия восстанавливается

Comment: Должно, вроде, работать так, как вам нужно. Пробовали другой браузер протестировать?

Comment: Пробовал firefox и chrome. Результат тот же

Comment: Я вот думаю, не может ли быть такое, что нужно что-то в настройках tomcat добавить? Но, по идее, мой web.xml должен перекрывать томкатовский

Comment: А cookie используются?

Comment: В браузере - да. По крайней мере, в chrome точно

Comment: @gregkukukev, возможно у вас в браузере/системе какие-то особенные настройки на этот счёт? Пробовали с других устройств проверять? Типа в одну сеть их поместить и на адрес хоста через браузер сходить? Например с другого компа или с телефона?

Comment: попробуйте добавить в session-config  <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>